# Upgrading Faraday gem: RuntimeError: Adapter should be set using the `adapter` method, not `use`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faraday

I'm relatively new to RoR, and now I want to upgrade faraday from 0.15.4 to 0.16.2 and I think I need to change the way I insert Faraday into the middleware stack. But  how do I do this?

After upgrading the faraday gem I get the following error from Minitest:

```
RuntimeError: Adapter should be set using the `adapter` method, not `use`
```

Usually googling the exact error message works out fine for me, unfortunately this time I'm less fortunate, only found the literal string in the Farady code :)

This error is raised by Faraday when it is used like below in one of my test files:

```rb
def extend_middleware(builder)
  builder.use Ahora::Middleware::RequestLogger, SemanticLogger[Reader]
  builder.use Faraday::Adapter::Typhoeus
end
```

I have the impression that the solution should be relatively straight-forward, only changing the `builder.use` line above. But I have no clue how I convert this to the `adapter` method as mentioned in the error message. It would help me greatly if someone could point out the difference between 'use' and 'adapter' methods (I'd like to understand the problem!) and possibly point me to a solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a doc that the Faraday team [put online](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/v1.0-rc1/UPGRADING.md) to help with any backwards-compayibility errors from version 0.15.4.

There's a section regarding your problem:

> In order to specify the adapter you now MUST use the #adapter method on the connection builder. If you don't do so and your adapter inherits from Faraday::Adapter then Faraday will raise an exception. Otherwise, Faraday will automatically push the default adapter at the end of the stack causing your request to be executed twice.

```rb
class OfficialAdapter < Faraday::Adapter
  ...
end

class MyAdapter
  ...
end

# This will raise an exception
conn = Faraday.new(...) do |f|
  f.use OfficialAdapter
end

# This will cause Faraday inserting the default adapter at the end of the stack
conn = Faraday.new(...) do |f|
  f.use MyAdapter
end

# You MUST use `adapter` method
conn = Faraday.new(...) do |f|
  f.adapter AnyAdapter
end
```

Comment: This takes the error away, but I'm not sure if it is semantically equivalent (will have to do some testing to see what `builder` actually does)

Comment: Turns out, `builder` actually _is_ a connection, so the fix was relatively straight-forward: 
```
  builder.adapter Faraday::Adapter::Typhoeus
```